# Removing Include Errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, opengl

I am getting a bunch of errors as follows:-

```
Error   1   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAccum' c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   4   error C2182: 'APIENTRY' : illegal use of type 'void'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   6   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1153    Viewer
Error   7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1153    Viewer
```

This is all that I include in the beginning of my code :-

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "arcball.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
```

It is interesting though that when I click on the first error it points me to the line

```
WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glAccum (GLenum op, GLfloat value);
```

in gl.h .I am not even including that file.Where are the errors coming from?

PS. dont know if itis important but I have saved the file as a .cpp.

Ok this is weird but I completely remove all the headers and it still shows me this error!!

Comment: glut.h is no longer distributed with the SDK.  Where did you get it from?  Provide a URL.

Comment: well i took it from the sample project here .https://agora.cs.illinois.edu/display/cs418sp11/Home  at the bottom of the page under discussions.Unzipped it , copied the glut.h and placed it in my project .

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing an include file `WinGDI.h`. `gl.h` is most likely included by the file `<GL/glut.h>`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinGDI.h> // <--------------------
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "arcball.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: Nope doesnt work ...I added that line which you said..Could it have something to do with project properties?